# Write table or csv that include multiple tabs in excel

Tags: r, csv, shiny

My question seems pretty straight forward but for some reason I haven't found any answer yet. :(

I build a shiny app and I want to use a download button for the computed matrices. Is there any way to use write.csv in order to download a .csv with multiple tabs (for different matrices), so the user isn't forced to download 3-4 different files?

Thank you in advance

Comment: CSVs can't have tabs, but you could use packages like `XLConnect` or `xlsx` to write directly to an Excel file, including on different sheets.

Comment: And if Excel files aren't an option, you could write multiple CSVs, `zip` them, and export the zip file to the user.

Comment: Or use something that can handle non-rectangular data, like `json`. Though that's possibly less userfriendly depending on your audience.

Comment: Another alternative to `XLConnect` and `xlsx`: [`openxlsx`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/openxlsx/index.html). Otherwise I second @Benjamin's suggested use of `zip`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding to all the comments, XLConnect is a good idea. The download handler code would be:

```
library(XLConnect)
output$dwnld <- donwloadHandler(
    filename = "xyz.xlsx"
},
    content = function(file) {
        wb <- loadWorkbook(file, create = TRUE)
        createSheet(wb, name="x")
        createSheet(wb, name="y")
        writeWorkSheet(wb, data=df_x, sheet=x, header=TRUE)
        writeWorkSheet(wb, data=df_y, sheet=y, header=TRUE)
        saveWorkbook(wb)
     }
)
```